Engineering reason as to why certain IS/PM brake adapters are front- and rear-specific?
I realize that IS front and rear differ by 20mm (160 native fork, 140 native frame), so that if I want to use 180mm front and 160mm rear rotors, there's one Avid adapter labelled "20mm IS" that would work for both front and back.
But certain other manufacturers, Hayes and Shimano in particular, make front-specific and rear-specific adapters that look different (compare Hayes #32 and #26 which are 180mm front-specific and 160mm rear-specific, respectively).
What is the reason for this? I did ask Hayes and their answer was:

These place the caliper if different locations to accommodate the
geometry of the caliper and rotor size

Which is a bit vague.

The positioning of the rear caliper is between the chainstay and seatstay, so that puts vertical limit. So, for larger rotors, the rear adapter should be designed to position the caliper further in the front direction (assuming that the caliper is mounted in the chainstay). On the front, there's no such constraint, but forces are higher, so it makes sense to optimise for distributing the effort between the two "IS bolts", rather than to fit the caliper within the rear triangle.
